# Custom listView with images and text

Tags: android

i want to dynamically create a custom ListView from the list of images in the drawable folder but i'm getting null pointer exception. Can somebody find what is wrong with my code. Here is my code...

```
public class ImageSelectionActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
// a list of resource IDs for the images we want to display
private Integer[] images;

// a context so we can later create a view within it
private Context myContext;

// store a cache of resized bitmaps
// Note: we're not managing the cache size to ensure it doesn't 
// exceed any maximum memory usage requirements
private Bitmap[] cache;

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
private Activity activity;

    // Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

    myContext = c;

    // Dynamically figure out which images we've imported
    // into the drawable folder, so we don't have to manually
    // type each image in to a fixed array.

    // obtain a list of all of the objects in the R.drawable class
    Field[] list = R.drawable.class.getFields();


    int count = 0, index = 0, j = list.length;

    // We first need to figure out how many of our images we have before
    // we can request the memory for an array of integers to hold their contents.

    // loop over all of the fields in the R.drawable class
    for(int i=0; i < j; i++)
        // if the name starts with img_ then we have one of our images!
        if(list[i].getName().startsWith("puzzle_")) count++;

    // We now know how many images we have. Reserve the memory for an 
    // array of integers with length 'count' and initialize our cache.
    images = new Integer[count];
    cache = new Bitmap[count];


    try {
        for(int i=0; i < j; i++)
            if(list[i].getName().startsWith("puzzle_")){
                images[index++] = list[i].getInt(null);
                }
    } catch(Exception e) {}


}

@Override
// the number of items in the adapter
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
// not implemented, but normally would return 
// the object at the specified position
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
// return the resource ID of the item at the current position
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return images[position];
}

// create a new ImageView when requested
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ImageView imgView = null;
    TextView textView;
    View itemView = convertView;        

    if(itemView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);         
         imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
         textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
         textView.setText("Hello");


    }


    // see if we've stored a resized thumb in cache
    if(cache[position] == null) {

        // create a new Bitmap that stores a resized
        // version of the image we want to display. 
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), images[position], options);

        // store the resized thumb in a cache so we don't have to re-generate it
        cache[position] = thumb;
    }

    // use the resized image we have in the cache
    imgView.setImageBitmap(cache[position]);


    return itemView;
}


}
```

**Here is the CatLog trace:**

```
    06-21 13:00:12.738: W/dalvikvm(30020): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413702a0)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at com.binay.project.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:101)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2472)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2307)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4657)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2004)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1825)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1120)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4604)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
06-21 13:00:12.743: E/AndroidRuntime(30020):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
```

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: what's on line 101 `ImageAdapter` class?

Comment: images[index++] = list[i].getInt(null); is this the line wherein you are facing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside getView, use myContext instead activity. Try,

```
 if(itemView == null) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    itemView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);         

}


imgView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
         textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
         textView.setText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the NPE is on line 101 which should be

```
Bitmap thumb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(myContext.getResources(), images[position], options);
```

I'm guessing that your context is null for some reason, as it is the only reference that you are getting from the constructor and not creating yourself. Try using getApplicationContext().getResources().

Comment: `myContext` is initialized in the constructor of ImageAdapter class

Comment: It's not - it is passed from the calling activity. It really shouldn't be null, but the other parameters look clearly assigned to me. Maybe the asker should separate the statement so that each argument is on its own line, then it will be clear which is throwing a NPE